# PIC16F1719 input RB5 hangs low

Tags: pic

I am designing a battery powered application with a PIC16F1719 and have a very strange problem that I have been unable to resolve.

In the design I am using RB5 and RB6 as inputs with interrupt on falling edge to wake the processor and resume from the sleep mode. The inputs have 1k pullup resistors to VDD.

The problem is that after some time (seconds to days) the RB5 input pin of the pic sinks the pullup to around 0.7v and starts reading low. This is not caused by the external switch that is supposed to wake the processor from sleepmode. Removing power and reapplying does not fix the problem, the pin still reads as low and starts the functionality unintended. The only way to make it go away for some time seems to be to apply 5V directly (high current) to the pin.

This only happens to the RB5 pin, over and over again. It has never happened to the RB6 or any other pin. I have checked the connection, the software, swapped the microcontroller ...

What could cause this problem? Have I overlooked something in the datasheet? I am running out of ideas ...

Adding some parts of the software:

```c
/* Configuration */

// CONFIG1
#pragma config FOSC = INTOSC    // Oscillator Selection Bits (INTOSC oscillator: I/O function on CLKIN pin)
#pragma config WDTE = NSLEEP    // Watchdog Timer Enable (WDT enabled while running and disabled in Sleep)
#pragma config PWRTE = OFF      // Power-up Timer Enable (PWRT disabled)
#pragma config MCLRE = OFF      // MCLR Pin Function Select (MCLR/VPP pin function is digital input if LVP bit is also 0.)
#pragma config CP = OFF         // Flash Program Memory Code Protection (Program memory code protection is disabled)
#pragma config BOREN = ON       // Brown-out Reset Enable (Brown-out Reset enabled)
#pragma config CLKOUTEN = OFF   // Clock Out Enable (CLKOUT function is disabled. I/O or oscillator function on the CLKOUT pin)
#pragma config IESO = ON        // Internal/External Switchover Mode (Internal/External Switchover Mode is enabled)
#pragma config FCMEN = ON       // Fail-Safe Clock Monitor Enable (Fail-Safe Clock Monitor is enabled)

// CONFIG2
#pragma config WRT = OFF        // Flash Memory Self-Write Protection (Write protection off)
#pragma config PPS1WAY = ON     // Peripheral Pin Select one-way control (The PPSLOCK bit cannot be cleared once it is set by software)
#pragma config ZCDDIS = ON      // Zero-cross detect disable (Zero-cross detect circuit is disabled at POR and can be enabled with ZCDSEN bit.)
#pragma config PLLEN = ON       // Phase Lock Loop enable (4x PLL is always enabled)
#pragma config STVREN = ON      // Stack Overflow/Underflow Reset Enable (Stack Overflow or Underflow will cause a Reset)
#pragma config BORV = LO        // Brown-out Reset Voltage Selection (Brown-out Reset Voltage (Vbor), low trip point selected.)
#pragma config LPBOR = OFF      // Low-Power Brown Out Reset (Low-Power BOR is disabled)
#pragma config LVP = OFF        // Low-Voltage Programming Enable (High-voltage on MCLR/VPP must be used for programming)
```

```
/* Prepare the processor and then go to sleep */
void SystemSleep()
{
    /* Turn off interrupt on change on RB4 */
    IOCBNbits.IOCBN4 = 0;

    /* Sleep the processor */
    SLEEP();

    /* When we resume, reset the processor */
    RESET();
}

/* System initialize */
void SystemInitialize()
{
    /**************************************************************************/
    /* 32 MHz HF */

    OSCCONbits.SPLLEN = 1;
    OSCCONbits.IRCF = 0b1110;
    OSCCONbits.SCS = 0;


    /**************************************************************************/
    /* Clear the ports */

    TRISA = 255;
    TRISB = 255;
    TRISC = 255;
    TRISD = 255;
    TRISE = 15;

    LATA = 0;
    LATB = 0;
    LATC = 0;
    LATD = 0;
    LATE = 0;


    /**************************************************************************/
    /* Digital IO */

    ANSELA = 0;
    ANSELB = 0;
    ANSELC = 0;
    ANSELD = 0;
    ANSELE = 0;


    /**************************************************************************/
    /* Enable weak pull ups */

    //OPTION_REGbits.nWPUEN = 0;


    /**************************************************************************/
    /* Timer 0 setup. Overflow every 1.024 ms*/

    OPTION_REGbits.TMR0CS = 0;  /* Fosc / 4 */
    OPTION_REGbits.PSA = 0;     /* Prescaler is assigned to timer 0 */
    OPTION_REGbits.PS = 0b011;  /* 16x prescaler */

    INTCONbits.TMR0IE = 1;      /* Enable timer 0 interrupt */


    /**************************************************************************/
    /* Timer 2 setup. Overflow every 256 instructions */

    PIE1bits.TMR2IE = 1;    /* Enable timer2 interrupts */

    INTCONbits.PEIE = 1;    /* Enable peripheral interrupts */

    PR2 = 255;  /* Period match register = 255 */

    T2CONbits.T2CKPS = 0;   /* 1:1 prescaler */
    T2CONbits.T2OUTPS = 0;  /* 1:1 postscaler */
    T2CONbits.TMR2ON = 1;   /* Enable timer 2 */


    /**************************************************************************/
    /* Interrupt on change, RB4, negative edge */

    INTCONbits.IOCIE = 1;   /* Enable interrupts on change */

    IOCBNbits.IOCBN4 = 1;   /* Interrupt on change on RB4 negative edge */
    IOCBNbits.IOCBN5 = 1;   /* Interrupt on change on RB5 negative edge */
    IOCBNbits.IOCBN6 = 1;   /* Interrupt on change on RB6 negative edge */


    /**************************************************************************/
    /* Enable global interrupts */

    INTCONbits.GIE = 1;
}
```

The IO is handled by an IO layer

Each pin has an IO pin object were its relevant registers and bit number and such is stored

```
/* IO object */
typedef struct
{
    volatile unsigned char* tris;
    volatile unsigned char* port;
    volatile unsigned char* lat;
    unsigned char b : 3;
    unsigned char dir : 1;
    unsigned char invert : 1;
    unsigned char changed : 1;
    unsigned char blink : 2;
    unsigned int blink_counter;
    unsigned char value : 1;
    unsigned char bounce_counter : 3;
} IO_t;
```

This is the IO module. I have search the code but cant find any bugs. InitilizePin is only called upon start of the program and IO_PIN_15 is only used to read.

```
/*
 * File:   io.c
 * Author: Viktor
 *
 * Created on den 23 november 2019, 08:25
 */

#include "io.h"
#include <pic16f1719.h>

/* Pin structs */
IO_t io_pin_1 = {&TRISC, &PORTC, &LATC, 7};
IO_t io_pin_2 = {&TRISD, &PORTD, &LATD, 4};
IO_t io_pin_3 = {&TRISD, &PORTD, &LATD, 5};
IO_t io_pin_4 = {&TRISD, &PORTD, &LATD, 6};
IO_t io_pin_5 = {&TRISD, &PORTD, &LATD, 7};
IO_t io_pin_8 = {&TRISB, &PORTB, &LATB, 0};
IO_t io_pin_9 = {&TRISB, &PORTB, &LATB, 1};
IO_t io_pin_10 = {&TRISB, &PORTB, &LATB, 2};
IO_t io_pin_11 = {&TRISB, &PORTB, &LATB, 3};
IO_t io_pin_14 = {&TRISB, &PORTB, &LATB, 4};
IO_t io_pin_15 = {&TRISB, &PORTB, &LATB, 5};
IO_t io_pin_16 = {&TRISB, &PORTB, &LATB, 6};
IO_t io_pin_17 = {&TRISB, &PORTB, &LATB, 7};
IO_t io_pin_18 = {&TRISE, &PORTE, &LATE, 3};
IO_t io_pin_19 = {&TRISA, &PORTA, &LATA, 0};
IO_t io_pin_20 = {&TRISA, &PORTA, &LATA, 1};
IO_t io_pin_21 = {&TRISA, &PORTA, &LATA, 2};
IO_t io_pin_22 = {&TRISA, &PORTA, &LATA, 3};
IO_t io_pin_23 = {&TRISA, &PORTA, &LATA, 4};
IO_t io_pin_24 = {&TRISA, &PORTA, &LATA, 5};
IO_t io_pin_25 = {&TRISE, &PORTE, &LATE, 0};
IO_t io_pin_26 = {&TRISE, &PORTE, &LATE, 1};
IO_t io_pin_27 = {&TRISE, &PORTE, &LATE, 2};
IO_t io_pin_30 = {&TRISA, &PORTA, &LATA, 7};
IO_t io_pin_31 = {&TRISA, &PORTA, &LATA, 6};
IO_t io_pin_32 = {&TRISC, &PORTC, &LATC, 0};
IO_t io_pin_35 = {&TRISC, &PORTC, &LATC, 1};
IO_t io_pin_36 = {&TRISC, &PORTC, &LATC, 2};
IO_t io_pin_37 = {&TRISC, &PORTC, &LATC, 3};
IO_t io_pin_38 = {&TRISD, &PORTD, &LATD, 0};
IO_t io_pin_39 = {&TRISD, &PORTD, &LATD, 1};
IO_t io_pin_40 = {&TRISD, &PORTD, &LATD, 2};
IO_t io_pin_41 = {&TRISD, &PORTD, &LATD, 3};
IO_t io_pin_42 = {&TRISC, &PORTC, &LATC, 4};
IO_t io_pin_43 = {&TRISC, &PORTC, &LATC, 5};
IO_t io_pin_44 = {&TRISC, &PORTC, &LATC, 6};

/* Pin struct pointers */
IO_t* const IO_PIN_1 = &io_pin_1;
IO_t* const IO_PIN_2 = &io_pin_2;
IO_t* const IO_PIN_3 = &io_pin_3;
IO_t* const IO_PIN_4 = &io_pin_4;
IO_t* const IO_PIN_5 = &io_pin_5;
IO_t* const IO_PIN_8 = &io_pin_8;
IO_t* const IO_PIN_9 = &io_pin_9;
IO_t* const IO_PIN_10 = &io_pin_10;
IO_t* const IO_PIN_11 = &io_pin_11;
IO_t* const IO_PIN_14 = &io_pin_14;
IO_t* const IO_PIN_15 = &io_pin_15;
IO_t* const IO_PIN_16 = &io_pin_16;
IO_t* const IO_PIN_17 = &io_pin_17;
IO_t* const IO_PIN_18 = &io_pin_18;
IO_t* const IO_PIN_19 = &io_pin_19;
IO_t* const IO_PIN_20 = &io_pin_20;
IO_t* const IO_PIN_21 = &io_pin_21;
IO_t* const IO_PIN_22 = &io_pin_22;
IO_t* const IO_PIN_23 = &io_pin_23;
IO_t* const IO_PIN_24 = &io_pin_24;
IO_t* const IO_PIN_25 = &io_pin_25;
IO_t* const IO_PIN_26 = &io_pin_26;
IO_t* const IO_PIN_27 = &io_pin_27;
IO_t* const IO_PIN_30 = &io_pin_30;
IO_t* const IO_PIN_31 = &io_pin_31;
IO_t* const IO_PIN_32 = &io_pin_32;
IO_t* const IO_PIN_35 = &io_pin_35;
IO_t* const IO_PIN_36 = &io_pin_36;
IO_t* const IO_PIN_37 = &io_pin_37;
IO_t* const IO_PIN_38 = &io_pin_38;
IO_t* const IO_PIN_39 = &io_pin_39;
IO_t* const IO_PIN_40 = &io_pin_40;
IO_t* const IO_PIN_41 = &io_pin_41;
IO_t* const IO_PIN_42 = &io_pin_42;
IO_t* const IO_PIN_43 = &io_pin_43;
IO_t* const IO_PIN_44 = &io_pin_44;

static IO_t* const io_array[] =
{
    IO_PIN_1,
    IO_PIN_2,
    IO_PIN_3,
    IO_PIN_4,
    IO_PIN_5,
    IO_PIN_8,
    IO_PIN_9,
    IO_PIN_10,
    IO_PIN_11,
    IO_PIN_14,
    IO_PIN_15,
    IO_PIN_16,
    IO_PIN_17,
    IO_PIN_18,
    IO_PIN_19,
    IO_PIN_20,
    IO_PIN_21,
    IO_PIN_22,
    IO_PIN_23,
    IO_PIN_24,
    IO_PIN_25,
    IO_PIN_26,
    IO_PIN_27,
    IO_PIN_30,
    IO_PIN_31,
    IO_PIN_32,
    IO_PIN_35,
    IO_PIN_36,
    IO_PIN_37,
    IO_PIN_38,
    IO_PIN_39,
    IO_PIN_40,
    IO_PIN_41,
    IO_PIN_42,
    IO_PIN_43,
    IO_PIN_44
};

static uint16_t blink_array[] = {0, 400, 100, 50};

/* Set or clear a bit in the register reg */
static void IOWriteBit(volatile unsigned char* const reg, unsigned char b, unsigned char v)
{
    if (v == 0)
    {
        /* Clear bit */
        *reg = *reg & ~(1 << b);
    }
    else
    {
        /* Set bit */
        *reg = *reg | (1 << b);
    }
}

/* Read the bit b in the register reg */
static unsigned char IOReadBit(volatile unsigned char* const reg, unsigned char b)
{
    return (*reg >> b) & 1;
}

/* Debounce an input pin */
static void IODebounce(IO_t* pin)
{
    /* Return if not an input */
    if ( !(pin -> dir == IO_INPUT) )
        return;

    /* Read the pin state */
    uint08_t read = IOReadBit(pin -> port, pin -> b);

    /* Invert if needed */
    if ((pin -> invert) == TRUE)
        read = !read;

    /* Increment/decrement the bounce counter */
    if ( read == IO_HIGH && ((pin -> bounce_counter) < 7) )
    {
        pin -> bounce_counter = (pin -> bounce_counter) + 1;
    }
    else if ( read == IO_LOW && ((pin -> bounce_counter) > 0) )
    {
        pin -> bounce_counter = (pin -> bounce_counter) - 1;
    }

    unsigned char value_old = pin -> value;

    /* Check if the pin state should be updated */
    if ((pin -> bounce_counter) == 7)
    {
        /* Set a new high pin state */
        pin -> value = IO_HIGH;
    }
    else if ((pin -> bounce_counter) == 0)
    {
        /* Set a new low pin state */
        pin -> value = IO_LOW;
    }
    else
    {
        /* Keep the pin state */
    }

    /* Set the changed flag if the pin changed state */
    if (value_old != pin -> value)
    {
        pin -> changed = TRUE;
    }
}

/* Calculate the blinking */
static void IOBlink(IO_t* pin)
{
    if (pin -> blink == BLINK_OFF)
        return;

    if ( pin -> blink_counter > blink_array[pin -> blink] )
    {
        if (pin -> value == IO_HIGH)
            IOWritePin(pin, IO_LOW);
        else
            IOWritePin(pin, IO_HIGH);

        pin -> blink_counter = 0;
    }
    else
        pin -> blink_counter = pin -> blink_counter + 1;
}

/* Poll the IO module every 1 ms */
void IOPoll()
{
    for (unsigned char n = 0; n < (sizeof(io_array) / sizeof(IO_t* const)); n++)
    {
        IO_t* pin = io_array[n];

        IODebounce(pin);
        IOBlink(pin);
    }
}

/* Initialize a pin */
void IOInitializePin(IO_t* pin, unsigned char dir, bool_t invert)
{
    pin -> dir = dir;
    //pin -> pullup = pullup;
    pin -> invert = invert;

    pin -> value = 0;
    pin -> bounce_counter = 0;
    pin -> blink = BLINK_OFF;
    pin -> blink_counter = 0;

    /* Set the TRISX bit */
    IOWriteBit(pin -> tris, pin -> b, pin -> dir);

    /* Set LATX */
    IOWriteBit(pin -> lat, pin -> b, IO_LOW);

    /* Set WPUX */
    //IOWriteBit(pin -> wpu, pin -> b, pin -> pullup);
}

/* Read a pin */
bool_t IOReadPin(IO_t* pin)
{
    return IOReadBit(pin -> port, pin -> b);
}

/* Read a pin debounced */
bool_t IOReadPinDebounced(IO_t* pin)
{
    /* Return the debounced value */
    return pin -> value;
}

/* Read if the pin has changed state */
bool_t IOChanged(IO_t* pin)
{
    /* Read the changed state */
    bool_t c = pin -> changed;

    /* Reset the value when read */
    pin -> changed = FALSE;

    return c;
}

/* Write to a pin */
void IOWritePin(IO_t* pin, unsigned char v)
{
    /* Set the value in the struct */
    pin -> value = v;

    unsigned char value = pin -> value;

    if (pin -> invert == TRUE)
        value = !value;

    /* Write to the hardware */
    IOWriteBit(pin -> lat, pin -> b, value);
}

/* Toggle a pin */
void IOTogglePin(IO_t* pin)
{
    IOWritePin(pin, !(pin -> value));
}

/* Set the blinking on a pin */
void IOSetBlink(IO_t* pin, IOBlinkType_t type)
{
    pin -> blink = type;
    pin -> blink_counter = MAX_U16;

    IOWritePin(pin, IO_LOW);
}
```

This is how the input circuit looks. The switches are connected with about 1m long wires. So there is risk for EMI, but it is strange that it is only RB5 I have problems with.

[image]

Comment: What is connected to RB5, a switch? How far away? Different board? Is a low-pass RC filter, TVS, or similar used to protect RB5? Are adequate decoupling capacitors used? Is EMI being picked up from something else?  Is TRISB5 somehow being set to output?

Comment: show some code. RB5 is also Gate for Timer 1.

Comment: I added some stuff to the question.

Comment: Your symptoms possibly suggest dreaded **latch-up**  (and perhaps @rdtsc is hinting at that too ). Can be very hard to troubleshoot - being a rare one-time short event.

Comment: Thanks for the input! It could be latch-up, a power cycle however dont fix the problem. It seem like the pin somehow gets damaged, perhaps from EMI and lower the input impedance so that the pullup resistor no longer is strong enough.

Comment: @user300219 - Hi, (a) To confirm, this is a PIC16**F**1719 not a 16**LF**1719, yes? (b) Are you using a version in socketed DIP package (so it can be removed easily), or is it soldered directly to the PCB (any package)? (c) Can you supply the full schematic (showing all external switches etc. and the power supply)? (d) What's the history of this design? Did you ever *not* have this problem e.g. earlier bench prototypes? Can you identify changes to design or usage just before this started? (e) You mention not seeing this with RB6. More detail needed about differences in connections RB5 vs. RB6.

Comment: Hi and sorry for delayed reply! a) I am using the PIC16F1719 and not the low voltage version b) Im using the TQFP-44 package c) I dont have an up to date schematic and layout, but the schematic is the same as for RB6 and the other input pins (illustrated in the post) d) I have had the problem from the start, then redesigned the circuit a bit, but the problem remains. e) It is schematically the same, in the layout there could of course be a bit different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is no definitive answer to what causes the pin to be damaged and stop working properly, but here is my conclusions from your feedback an also from my Microchip customer support case.

1. The problem with the pin seems that it is physically damaged since a powercycle or reflash dont fix the pin.
2. The code seems to be fine with no incorrect settings
3. The input circuit is probably not sufficient to protect the pin(s) from getting damaged. I will redesign the board and add clamping schottky diodes + rc filter or use optocouplers on the input pins.

This article shows some good input circuitry design:

https://www.digikey.com/en/articles/techzone/2012/apr/protecting-inputs-in-digital-electronics

Thanks everyone!